# Issues parsing JSON with JQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm accessing an API through JQuery/JSON. I can get the entire JSON block to display on a page using the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('un:pw'));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, data){
        console.log("(1)Static error message");
        console.log("(2)Output of textStatus " + textStatus);
        console.log("(3)Output of data " + data);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var myData = data;
        $('#myData').html('<p>'+ myData +'<p>') 
    }
})
```

However, when I try to access a key/value from that JSON, I get undefined. I think I'm not parsing the JSON correctly. Here's an example of some code I tried inside the success function:

```
$.each(myData.blockOne, function(data){
    $('#myData').html('<p>'+ this.blockOne.id +'<p>')
});
```

Here's is an example of the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ItemName": {
            "id": "XYZ",
            "caseNumber": "123"
        },
        "blockOne": [
            {
                "id": "ABC",
                "subject": "321",
            }
        ],
        "blockTwo": [
            {
                "id": "EFG",
                "subject": "456",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ItemName": {
            "id": "HIJ",
            "caseNumber": "333"
        },
        "blockOne": [
            {
                "id": "JIL",
                "subject": "999",
            }
        ],
        "blockTwo": [
            {
                "id": "OPE",
                "subject": "778",
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I'm trying to output something like the following:

*Item*

ID: XYZ

Case: 123

Block 1:

- ID: ABC
- Subject: 321

Block 2:

- ID: EFG
- Subject: 456

---

*Item*

ID: HIJ

Case: 333

Block 1:

- ID: JIL
- Subject: 999

Block 2:

- ID: OPE
- Subject: 778

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ajax request is already parsing the response from json to an object/array.  This is because you have `dataType: 'json'` which tells ajax that you expect json to be returned so it auto parses it for you.  You are then taking the already parsed object and appending it to a paragraph string.  If you are expecting that to still be a string, you need to change your `dataType` declaration to `text`.

Comment: For reference: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It looks like the outer container of the data is an array, and you're trying to access the "blockOne" property from it.

Comment: I think you want `$.each(myData`, not `$.each(myData.blockOne`

Comment: I think @CharlesBamford is on to something, but I'm not sure what to change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `$.each()`, you need to loop through `myData` array instead of `myData.blockOne` because `myData.blockOne` returns only the data of the `blockOne` object.

```js
var myData = [{
    "ItemName": {
      "id": "XYZ",
      "caseNumber": "123"
    },
    "blockOne": [{
      "id": "ABC",
      "subject": "321",
    }],
    "blockTwo": [{
      "id": "EFG",
      "subject": "456",
    }]
  },
  {
    "ItemName": {
      "id": "HIJ",
      "caseNumber": "333"
    },
    "blockOne": [{
      "id": "JIL",
      "subject": "999",
    }],
    "blockTwo": [{
      "id": "OPE",
      "subject": "778",
    }]
  },
];

var html = "";

$.each(myData, function() {
  html += `
    <p>Item</p>
    <p>ID :${this.ItemName.id}</p>
    <p>Case :+${this.ItemName.caseNumber}</p>
    <p>Block 1:</p>
    <ul>
       <li>ID :${this.blockOne[0].id}</li>
       <li>Subject :${this.blockOne[0].subject}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Block 2:</p>
    <ul>
       <li>ID :${this.blockTwo[0].id}</li>
       <li>Subject :${this.blockTwo[0].subject}</li>
    </ul>
    `
});

$('#myData').html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myData"></div>
```

Comment: This is close, but it only shows the first instance. Even with your example. I put it in a JSFiddle here → https://jsfiddle.net/seg7vf69/

Comment: What did you mean by instance? Are there multiple elements in the array?

Comment: Yeah even in the example you posted there are two "ItemName" blocks. Your code only shows one.

Comment: So sorry about that. I updated my code. Please check